# django queryset - classify and filter by value

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

I have model with two attributes:

```
class Fruit(models.Model)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   days_left_to_consumption = models.IntegerField()
```

that gives me database objects:

```
{"name":"apple", "days_left_to_consumption": 2},
{"name":"apple", "days_left_to_consumption": 3},
{"name":"pineaple", "days_left_to_consumption": 2},
{"name":"pineaple", "days_left_to_consumption": 1}
```

I want to create queryset to classify results by "name" attribute (every diffrent fruit name occurs only one time) but get for every diffrient fruit object with the higher value of "days_left_to_consumption". The result I want to get from the upper example is:

```
{"name":"apple", "days_left_to_consumption": 3},
{"name":"pineaple", "days_left_to_consumption": 2}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: At the very least, you can find the highest one for each name separately with Fruit.objects.filter(name=FRUIT_NAME).order_by("-days_left_to_consumption").first() and combine them after the fact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group the items by name and get the maximum days_left_to_consumption like this:

```
from django.db.models import Max
fruits = Fruit.objects.values('name').annotate(max_days_left_to_consumption=Max('days_left_to_consumption'))
```

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty close, but what when I want to get objects, not only json's params?